# Turning PNG into Numpy array -> Change color values -> combine channels and save image

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-imaging-library

The errors I keep receiving through the 3.9.6 IDLE indicate an error turning the 2D arrays into 3D arrays, however as I troubleshoot the error I kept receiving the buffer error listed below:

> AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'astype'

> ValueError: buffer is not large enough

**Program Objective**

The program is meant to take an image and change the values of each channel based on the number of desired phots to be output. A change is made to each number in the arrays, increasing or decreasing the value based on where the original value is compared to 0 and 255, decreasing the value if the number is closer to 255, and increasing the value if it is closer to 0. The alpha channel is ignored along with any 0's in the RGB arrays. The program calculates how much each step will be based on the number the user inputs, moving it between 1 and 10, and then divides the number by 255 to get the step size, which at its smallest is 24.
The Program should then combine the channels with the adjusted values, and save it as a new Image.

**The Code**

```
import numpy as np
import easygui
import os


def arrUpdate(x, y, inc, arrPass):  # pass loop, Height, Width, and offset value
   for Dy in range(y):
       for Dx in range(x):
           # Scan Each row in order from top down and left to right and change the value. XY sort
           if arrPass[Dy][Dx] == 0:
               Dx += 1
               break
           elif int(arrPass[Dy][Dx]) > 128:
               arrPass[Dy][Dx] = arrPass[Dy][Dx] + inc
           elif int(arrPass[Dy][Dx]) <= 128:
               arrPass[Dy][Dy] = arrPass[Dy][Dx] - inc
           Dx += 1
       Dy += 1
       return arrPass

def newPNG(version, combined):
   FinalRender = np.array([np.dstack(combined)])
   new_img = Image.fromarray(FinalRender.astype('uint8'), 'RGBA')
   FinalPath = os.path.join(newPath, fileNameStr)
   new_img.save(FinalPath)
   print("Image " + str(version + 1) + " Rendered")


###################################################################################################


fields = ["Original File Name:", "Number of versions: \n(1 - 10)"]
fieldReturn = easygui.multenterbox('Information Required', 'Auto Hue Shift', fields)


fileName = fieldReturn[0]
fileNameStr = str(fileName)
if '.png' in fileNameStr:   # Leaves.png
   name = fileNameStr.replace(".png","")
else: # Leaves
   name = fileNameStr
   fileNameStr = (fileNameStr + '.png')


itt = int(fieldReturn[1])   #iteration

#cwd = "/Users/piedr/Documents/Python"
cwd = os.getcwd() 
newPath = os.path.join(cwd, name)
isPath = os.path.isdir(newPath)
if isPath == False:
   os.mkdir(newPath, 0o777)
if isPath == True:
   print('Directory already exists')


img = Image.open(fileNameStr).convert('RGBA')
arr = (np.array(np.asarray(img).astype('uint8')))

rgb = arr
r, g, b, a = rgb[..., 0], rgb[..., 1], rgb[..., 2], rgb[..., 3]

inc = None
while True:
   if itt == 0:
       print('No Value Provided\nExiting...')
       exit()
   elif itt > 10:
       itt = (itt / 10)
   else:
       inc = itt / 255
       break

length = (len(arr[0])) - 1
height = (len(arr[0, 0])) - 1
num = 1
for num in range(itt):
   # Control Iteration Count anf color Transition
   # RED
   newRGB = arrUpdate(length, height, inc, r)
   # GREEN
   newRGB = arrUpdate(length, height, inc, g)
   # BLUE
   newRGB = arrUpdate(length, height, inc, b)
   newPNG(num, newRGB)
   num += 1
   
#print(str(r) + ' RED\n')
#print(str(g) + ' GREEN\n')
#print(str(b) + ' BLUE')
```

I have tried multiple formats of np.array, np.asarray, etc.. but I don't know specifically what it should be, and how it should translate.

Comment: You have many instances of `==`, `<<` and `>>` where you actually need `=`, `<`, and `>`.  How is that happening?

Comment: You don't need `Dx += 1` and `Dy += 1` in your loop.  The `for` statement handles that for you.

Comment: You're overwriting `newRGB` each time; each new call replaces the old contents.  You're not building up a list of 3 elements.

Comment: Just a mistake I made, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: If you are aware of errors in your code as a result of @TimRoberts assistance, please click `edit` under your question and update it with your latest/greatest code so that other folk don't waste their time trying to help you improve something you already know to be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem description is nonsense.  "The program calculates how much each step will be based on the number the user inputs, moving it between 1 and 10, and then divides the number by 255 to get the step size, which at its smallest is 24".  What the hell does that mean?  What kind of numbers are they inputting?

And why do you think you need to iterate anything?  If you subtract the minimum  value of 24 and do it 10 times, you will have nothing but 0 and 255.  I SUSPECT they want the user to enter a value between 1 and 10, and then want you to add or subtract 255 / N from each pixel.  So, entering 5 results in an increment of 51.  That's what I've done here.

You had +/- backwards.  You're supposed to reduce big values and increase small values.

Note that I have eliminated `easygui` and just pass the two parameters (file name and increment value) on the command line.

By the way, manipulating numpy arrays element by element like this is hopelessly slow.  This takes close to a minute with a megapixel image.  You need to be able to do these things in bulk, which is rather easy with numpy.  numpy can tell you which values are < 128 and which are > 128, and then you can do a single operation on the whole set.

```
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

fileName = sys.argv[1]
itt = int(sys.argv[2])

def arrUpdate(arrPass, inc):  # pass array and offset value
    for Dy in range(arrPass.shape[0]):
        if Dy % 50 == 0:
            print(Dy,end='\r')
        for Dx in range(arrPass.shape[1]):
            if arrPass[Dy][Dx] == 0:
                continue
            elif arrPass[Dy][Dx] >= 128:
                arrPass[Dy][Dx] = min(arrPass[Dy][Dx] - inc, 255)
            else:
                arrPass[Dy][Dx] = max(arrPass[Dy][Dx] + inc, 0 )
    print()
    return arrPass

def newPNG(version, finalRender):
   new_img = Image.fromarray(finalRender.astype('uint8'), 'RGBA')
   parts = os.path.splitext(fileName)
   FinalPath = parts[0] + '_' + str(version+1) + '.png'
   new_img.save(FinalPath)
   print(f"Image {FinalPath} Rendered")

img = Image.open(fileName).convert('RGBA')
rgb = np.array(img).astype('uint8')

if itt == 0:
   print('No Value Provided\nExiting...')
   sys.exit()

inc = 255 // itt

print(rgb.shape)
r, g, b, a = rgb[..., 0], rgb[..., 1], rgb[..., 2], rgb[..., 3]

num = 1

r = arrUpdate( r, inc )
g = arrUpdate( g, inc )
b = arrUpdate( b, inc )

rgb[:,:,0] = r
rgb[:,:,1] = g
rgb[:,:,2] = b
newPNG(num, rgb)
```

Comment: I realize ive made some pretty careless mistakes as Ive progressed through iterations of this code. The images input are meant to be pixel art, generally up to 32x32, so doing it this way was on purpose, i know its slower but its not important. The version you created doesnt do exactly what i wanted in the way i planned, however it does help a lot so thanks!